# is it possible to execute two validation methods of Reads on same JsPath

Tags: json, playframework

I want to validate a password field as follows:

First check that the password has only lower case
Then check that its length is min 8 characters.

I have written the two validation codes as follows:

```
/*check lowercase*/

def checkPasswordCase[T]: Reads[String] = {
  Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("Password not in lowercase"))(str => {
    (str.matches("""[a-z]+"""))
  })
}


/*check length*/
def checkPasswordLength[T](min:Int): Reads[String] = {
  Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("Invalid password length"))(str => {
    (str.length >= min)
  })
}
```

I called the code as follows but got compilation error `Cannot prove that String <:< String => C.`

```
(JsPath \ "user" \ "password").read[String](checkPasswordCase)(checkPasswordLength(8)) and ...
```

I tried using Reads.minLength(8) but got a different error.

Couldn't I use two validation codes back to back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either the `keepAnd` *or* `andKeep` [validators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Validation-with-Reads) to do this. These combinators will run both `Reads` but only keep the *successful* result of either the left or right operands:

```
val r = (JsPath \ "user" \ "password").read[String](
  checkPasswordCase keepAnd checkPasswordLength(8))

val js = Json.obj("user" -> Json.obj("password" -> "FOO"))
println(js.validate[String](r))
// JsError(List((/user/password,List(
//          ValidationError(List(Password not in lowercase),WrappedArray()), 
//          ValidationError(List(Invalid password length),WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: didn't work, unfortunately. Got `diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[M] starting with method ArrayReads in trait DefaultReads` when I used keepAnd or keepAnd. `(JsPath \ "user" \ "password").read[String]((checkPasswordCase) andKeep (Reads.minLength(8))) and...`

Comment: This might be caused by the redundant `[T]` in your definition of `checkPasswordCase` and `checkPasswordLength`. These validators only handle strings so are not actually generic. Try just removing the `[T]`. Alternately, be explicit with the type by doing `checkPasswordCase[String]`.

Comment: Removed [T]from definitions of checkPasswordCase and checkPasswordLength. Then `(JsPath \ "user" \ "password").read[String]((checkPasswordCase) andKeep (checkPasswordLength(8))) and` worked. Thanks.